# Pydev Package Explorer Issues

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have just installed Pydev on my existing copy of Eclipse for Java, running on OSX 10.7.  When I make a new pydev package, I click away from the default directory for my java files and into one for python files.  Once it is created, the project shows in the pydev package explorer window.  However, once I close the package, it disappears from the pydev explorer window, but shows in the java explorer window (under java perspective).  I can run the python project from the java perspective, but I want to try and keep my projects separated (infuriating).

Also, if I want to create a new pydev package, I have to first delete a .project file from the python project directory before I can create a new package.

I've been looking around for an answer to this problem for a while, and most talk about changing different filter settings in the explorers, but the filter settings for both pydev and java seems to indicate what I want it to do (key word seems).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've wasted too much time on this triviality.  Thanks.

Comment: I haven't been able to follow what you meant... can you add an image explaining it?